Conflicting iCloud Drive settings?
I'm a bit confused about the iCloud Drive Desktop and Documents sync setting. I see two different settings in the System Settings app.
Apple ID > iCloud > iCloud Drive Desktop & Documents Folder is Disabled.
General > Storage > Store in iCloud > Desktop and Documents is Enabled.
In reality, my Desktop and Documents are not synced to iCloud and are only on the local drive. But why these conflicting settings? If Apple intended to sow confusion, they've succeeded.

What precisely do you see on your screen? The step 5 of the support article where you say “this one is disabled” is confusing to me since there are several toggles that can be in two states. The first link doesn’t proscribe behavior and reports the results of the settings you choose in the second link. Focus on the second is my advice to gain clarity on what you have asked the OS to do.

@bmike I've formulated it more simply. I hope you understand now.

Apple ID > iCloud > iCloud Drive Desktop & Documents Folder
This setting is the primary control to whether or not these two folders sync with iCloud. So if you want to sync them with iCloud, this is the setting to enable.
General > Storage > Store in iCloud > Desktop and Documents
This setting is more related to storage optimisation, the setting mentions that it will store all files (or Desktop and Documents folders depending on your settings) in iCloud when storage space is needed. So this will not store your folders in iCloud if you have enough storage space on your Mac.


Thank you, that makes sense.
